# Why is my C program to do simple depreciation not working?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C to calculate a salvage value after depreciation of something. However, in when I run this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv){
    printf("enter the purchase price, years of service, annual depreciation:\n");
    double purchasePrice, yearsOfService, annualDep;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &purchasePrice, &yearsOfService, &annualDep);
    printf("purchase price is %d dollars\n", purchasePrice);
    printf("years of service is %d years\n", yearsOfService);
    printf("annual depreciation is %d dollars\n", annualDep);
    double salvageValue = purchasePrice - (yearsOfService * annualDep);
    printf("The salvage value of the item is %d", salvageValue);

    return 0;
}
```

it prints out the purchasePrice instead of what the salvageValue should be. What is going on?

Comment: can you test wether (yearsOfService * annualDep) is zero by chance? just print it to see

Comment: yes it it; I added: printf("total loss is %d\n", (yearsOfService * annualDep) ); and it printed 0

Comment: Also, you're using the `%d` conversion specifier in your `scanf` call, yet you're passing a pointer to a double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your `scanf` call with:

```
scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &purchasePrice, &yearsOfService, &annualDep);
```

`scanf` requires that all passed pointers match the types of the conversion specifiers (and vice versa). You're passing pointers to `double`s, and the correct conversion specifier is `%lf`.

From the `scanf` manpage:

> `l` indicates either that the conversion will be one of d, i, o, u, x, X, or n and the  next pointer is a pointer to a long int or unsigned long int (rather than int), **or that the conversion will be one of e, f, or g and the next pointer is a  pointer  to  double  (rather  than  float)**.  Specifying two l characters is equivalent to L.  If used with %c or %s, the corresponding parameter  is  considered  as  a  pointer  to  a wide character or wide-character string respectively.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: why should this be long floats instead of doubles? I tried this; its still not working

Comment: `%lf` is used for doubles, because `%d` is used for decimals (which are ints).  Go figure.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't define a specific conversion specifier for doubles, so a combination of `l` and `f` must be used, see `man 3 scanf` for more info.

Comment: @AviG becaue the `printf` format specifier `%d` is wrong too. It should be `%f`. "d" does not mean "double". BTW there is no such thing as `long float`. The format specifier for `scanf` `"%lf"` means `double`.